# Clarification about a little doubt on the independence definition

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

A simple question I tried to ask in a little different form on another site, evidently without much success in making myself clear. I am retrying with (hopefully) clearer language.

I was looking at the definition of **independence** for two events.
$P(A|B) = P(A)$, with $P(B)$ not zero.

My little doubt is about a specific case where $A$ is strictly included in $B$. That is, $A$ implies $B$.

In this case, $P(A|B) = P(A) / P(B)$. Now assume that $P(B) = 1$.

In this case, $P(A|B) = P(A$) which satisfy the independence definition (does it?)

How is this reconciled with the fact that A implies B (and therefore cannot be "independent")? [to say that the occurrence of A guarantees the occurrence of B because it is a part of it seems to be the conceptual opposite of "independence".]

What am I getting wrong?

**update**

Link to the question mentioned in the comments.
Following a request by David K
[previous question mentioned in comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/635073/event-in-conditional-probability-and-independence-definition)

Comment: It shouldn’t be very surprising should it. If you know that B is a sure event, then you can think as B of your entire sample space, and the probability of A happening with respect to B is just the probability of A in this sample space.

Comment: The occurrence of A implies B because A is a part of B. So, it seems, you cannot have A without also having B. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Academic You can "think of" should not be the same" that they are coincident. Similarly, most events have a null probability, but they are not the empty set. Something is still not right; it seems we should consider removing this case from the "definition" (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Preliminary comments

Mathematical definitions are, by definition, mathematical.
While we would like them to align with our preconceived notions of meaning when they use common words (such as *independence*),
sometimes the best we can do is to get them to line up in the "normal use case," rather than in every possible "edge case" where the definition might apply.

Even the word "implies" in "$A$ implies $B$" has a special definition in mathematics that many people find unintuitive.
In particular, many people have trouble accepting the notion that a false statement implies all other statements, regardless of the truth of the other statement or the ability to derive one statement from the other.
In terms of sets, the empty set is a subset of every set.
(Many people have trouble with this fact too.)

People also have trouble understanding why "$A$ implies $B$" must be true when $B$ is true, regardless of the truth of $A$ or the ability to derive one statement from the other.

For that matter, many people balk simply at the inability to derive one statement from the other, for example, "If Tierra del Fuego is in the southern hemisphere then Henry VIII of England had six wives."
Mathematically, that's a true implication, but how are the number of Henry's  marriages and the location of Tierra del Fuego **not** independent of each other?

The case where $P(B) = 1$ is definitely an "edge case."
You are apparently unconcerned by the inability to use the formula
$P(A) = P(A\mid B)$ in the case where $P(B) = 0$,
so ask yourself why you are concerned with the interpretation of the formula for the case where $P(B) = 1$, and whether that concern is really relevant to your ability to use this definition.

I think a much bigger objection to this definition is that it allows $A$ to be independent of $B$ while $B$ is not independent of $A$
(in particular, when $P(A)=0$).
That asymmetry bothers me more than dealing with the edge cases.
I prefer the definition that events $A$ and $B$ are independent when

$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B). $$

Not only is this symmetric in $A$ and $B$, it also makes the edge cases $P(B)=0$ and $P(B)=1$ both relevant to the definition.

### Discussion

Independence of random events is defined so that it is about probability. Logical deduction is not the goal.

In your example, where $P(B)=1$, if you find out that $A$ occurred, what does it tell you about the probability of $B$?

It tells you nothing. The probability of $B$ given $A$ must be $1$ since $A$ implies $B$, but you already knew that the probability of $B$ was $1$ before you had any information about whether $A$ occurred.

Likewise, the occurrence of $B$ doesn't tell you anything new about the probability of whether $A$ occurred.

The most obvious case where $P(B)=1$ is the case where $B = \Omega$,
that is, $B$ is the entire probability space.
What sense does it make to say that there is a dependence in probability between the entire probability space and some other event?
Since the event $\Omega$ is absolutely guaranteed to occur no matter what,
in what way can it depend on some other event, or some other event depend on it?

Consider in particular the case where $A = \emptyset$, that is, $A$ is the null event, and therefore $P(A) = 0$. This is the one event that absolutely **cannot** occur under any circumstances. And it is certainly true that
$\emptyset \subseteq \Omega$. How does this link between $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ prevent us from saying that these two events are independent?

The cases where "independent events" trouble you are cases where the word "implies" (or the words "if" and "then") trouble many people.
I will venture to say that the problem is not just with the definition of "independence", but also with the definition of "implies".

Finally, note that in every case where $P(A) \neq 0$ and $P(B) \neq 1$
-- that is, in every "ordinary" case --
$A \subseteq B$ implies that $A$ and $B$ are not independent events.
This aligns well with intuition.
It's just in some weird edge cases that we get weird results from the definition, and patching the definition to eliminate those results would just make the definition more complicated and harder to use in practice.

Comment: Yes, I am talking of events only, not "logic". "A  occurred, what does it tell you about the probability of B?" If A occurred, it is contained in B. Therefore, B, too, occurred. Is that wrong?

Comment: Tell me how your knowledge of the probability of $B$ changes. Does $A$ make $B$ more likely? Less likely?

Comment: Well, that is a bit ironic. When I asked this question on another forum, I was accused of wanting to talk about "information" instead of events and dismissed as a sort of lunatic. And now that I am talking only about pure events (to avoid critics), I am being asked to talk about "knowledge.". There is nothing about information or knowledge in the axioms. I think we should first agree on what  language is allowed or stick to the set theory :-)

Comment: The key word is **probability**. I use that word with its full formal meaning. The other words such as “knowledge” and “information” mean only what they mean in informal English conversation and do not have the technical meaning that you encountered elsewhere. And if this is just about the technical definitions and not about the informal intuition, then there’s really nothing to discuss. Technically, the definition is the definition and it doesn’t matter what you think of it.

Comment: You will have to spend a long, long time to describe probability completely in terms of set theory. “$A$ is a subset of $B$” is not a statement about probability.

Comment: By the way, the responses you got on the other forum are part of the context of this question, which ideally should be edited into the question itself. A direct link to your question in that other forum would be useful, if possible.

Comment: Thank you, David. On your request, I am adding it to the question

Comment: Surely, definitions are a convention. But I guess the real intuitive point that is being made here is that defining independence through conditional probability does not seem to work conceptually in the case where A is strictly included in B.

Comment: David, I appreciate your discussion. I am still not fully "convinced." In particular, because probability is just an extension of boolean logic (implies or inclusion) and cannot go against it and make sense. I suspect that the problem resides rather in allowing the conditioning event B to fully contain the event A being conditioned and then using that cond. prob. as a definition for independence. This seems to be a source of logical incongruence, especially if one interprets the conditioning event as "information.". I will think more about the matter, and I also hope to hear more.

Comment: "Information" needs a formal definition, but I think when you find one, you will find that the occurrence of an event of probability $1$ provides no information about the probability of any other event. You seem to have an unshakeable conviction that just because $A$ implies $B$, there must be some kind of causal link or at least epistemological link between the two. But logic doesn't provide that.

Comment: I do not believe that inclusion implies causality. Take the point: "the occurrence of an event of probability 1 provides no information about the probability of any other event". I tell you that I draw from the real line either 2 or sqrt(2). Assess the probability of either one. Then I add this information: "The number drawn is irrational" 
Would the new information change your probability assessment ?

Comment: In your example, can you identify an event $B$ of probability $1$, identify another event $A$, and show how knowing **only** that $B$ occurred affects your assessment of the probability that $A$ occurred?

Comment: Yes, that was the example. One might argue that the probability of drawing an irrational from the reals is 1 (event B) (while any countable set has probability 0). If now you assigned a probability of 1/2 at each one of the two occurrences (2 and sqrt(2)) in A,. Once you know that it must be irrational, you are forced to change your probabilities, as the new information removes a point from the sample space.

Comment: You have not identified $A$ and $B$. While doing so, please also identify your sample space. Is the sample space $\mathbb R$, the set $\{2,\sqrt2\}$, or something else?

Comment: thank you. I feel like abusing your patience and kindness. I guess the idea was the following: take $x$ from $X$ uniform in $[\sqrt{2}, 2]$, B={x is irrational $\cup$ ($x$ is either $\sqrt{2}$ or $2$ )}, A={$x$ is $\sqrt{2}$}

Comment: So, simplifying, $B=\{(\text{$x$ irrational}) \cup (x=2)\}$, $P(B)=1$, and $P(A)=0$. And if we find out that $B$ occurred, we still have zero probability for $A$ to occur, because $P(A\mid B) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, David K, great discussion, very instructive. I am grateful for it and your generous effort.